# Swift - Weekday by current location by currentCalendar()

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, location, weekday

Today is Wednesday and I have this code

```
let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComps:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday , fromDate: NSDate())
let dayOfWeek:Int = dateComps.weekday
```

dayOfWeek is 4, but today is 3rd day of the week in Bulgaria.
Is in USA today is 4th day of the week? And how to determine when the week starts in different countries and regions ?
On my iPhone locale and calendar are set to Bulgarian calendar and locale and it knows that the week starts on Monday on my iMac also, but when I execute code it writes me 4...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the Gregorian calendar, the `weekday` property of `NSDateComponents` is always
1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday etc.

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().firstWeekday
```

gives the (index of the) first weekday in the current locale, that could be 1 in USA
and 2 in Bulgaria. Therefore

```
var dayOfWeek = dateComps.weekday + 1 - calendar.firstWeekday
if dayOfWeek <= 0 {
    dayOfWeek += 7
}
```

is the day of the week according to your locale. As a one-liner:

```
let dayOfWeek = (dateComps.weekday + 7 - calendar.firstWeekday) % 7 + 1
```

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: Date()) + 1 - calendar.firstWeekday
if dayOfWeek <= 0 {
    dayOfWeek += 7
}
```

Comment: To clarify this for others, I don't believe that `calendar.firstWeekday` is the "index of the first weekday". A value of 1 corresponds to Sunday and 2 corresponds to Monday, same as with `NSDateComponents`. Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which are the weekend days you can use this extension:

```
extension Calendar {

    /// Return the weekSymbol index for the first week end day
    var firstWeekendDay: Int {
        let firstWeekDay = self.firstWeekday
        return (firstWeekDay - 2) >= 0 ? firstWeekDay - 2 : firstWeekDay - 2 + 7
    }

    /// Return the weekSymbol index for the second week end day
    var secondWeekendDay: Int {
        let firstWeekDay = self.firstWeekday
        return (firstWeekDay - 1) >= 0 ? firstWeekDay - 1 : firstWeekDay - 1 + 7
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set firstWeekday on your Calendar.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293656-firstweekday